# "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have difficulties with ruby on rails syntax.

I got this error

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

```
class PersonalsController 
   def index

   end
   def create   
      @personal = Personal.new
   end
   def new
      @personal = Personal.new      
   end
   def show
      @personal = Personal.find([:id])
   end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @personal do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.submit %>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

the value of `@personal` is nil that's why you are getting error.

Change you code like this

```
def index
  @personal= Personal.all
end

form_for is helper method
```

check with this link   [form_helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)

Comment: I have a new problem now   undefined method `to_key' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: because now you have empty AtiveRecord::Relation object

Comment: I have added this and it helped @personal = Personal.new

Comment: There are couple of way to remove this error 1: use :Personal 2: use : :url methods .

Comment: Kindly read this article , you will get all the things   http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated since `@personal` was not set in the controller. So either you add a `@personal = Personal.new` to the `index` method, or set it to a specific database entry, e.g., `@personal = Personal.find(1)`

However, it seems strange that you have a form displaying a single record in the `index` view.

More likely, you want to have the form in your `new` or `edit` views (in the former case you typically use `new`, while in the latter case you would use the `find` method to find a specific record and let the user edit it).

In the `index` method, you usually use the controller to select a group of records (e.g., `@ps = Personal.all` to get all the records) and iterate over them in the view (`@ps.each do |person| .... end`)

P.S. The show method should probably use `Personal.find(params[:id])` instead of `Personal.find([:id])`

Comment: when I add 
   def index  
      @personal = Personal.find(params[:id])
   end 
I get this
   Couldn't find Personal with 'id'=

Comment: I guess your database does not have a record with the id you requested. Try creating a few records first. For example, run the rails console (`rails c`) and try: `p = Personal.new; p.save!; puts p.id`. This will save a new record and print its id.